# Not able to install packages in R with install.packages()

Tags: r, install.packages

I have installed R Version 3.0.2. I am trying to run association analysis on a dataset.

While trying to install the `arules` package, using the code:

```
install.packages(“arules”)
```

I get and error:

> Error: unexpected input in "install.packages(“arules")

Can you guide as to how I can install this package and use it to run association on an imported txt file using R?

Answer (score 8):

You appear to be using "smartquotes" instead of straight quotes like `"` around `arules`. R cannot recognize these. Change to straight quotes and everything should work.

Comment: Very good answer... I did not know that there is something called smart quotes until i ran into this problem